# I am trying to generate a median but I am getting errors (numpy) python

Tags: python

I am having an error with my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
median = str(sorted2 [length1/2])
IndexError: only integers, slices (':')
ellipsis C...), numpy.newaxis (“Non
e") and integer or boolean arrays are v
alid indices
```

This is the code that is generating the error I am using math to split a string into a list and then I am using numpy to generate the math surrounding that list (beginner)

```
import numpy as np
import math 
numbers=""
sorted1=[]
current=0
floored=0
ceiling=0
numbers = input("array of numbers ")
numbers = numbers.split()
sorted1 = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in numbers]
sorted2 = np.sort(sorted1)
total=0
Finalmedian=0
print(" ")
print(sorted2)
print(" ")
for i in sorted2:
        current = current + i
finalmode = current/len(numbers)
print("MEAN: " + str(finalmode))
print(" ")
if np.bincount(sorted2).argmax() > sorted2[0]:
        print("MODE: "+str(np.bincount(sorted2).argmax()))
else:
        print("MODE: N/A or 1")
length1 = len(sorted2)
print(" ")
length2 = length1 - 1
if (length1 % 2) == 0: 
        length2 = length2/2
        floored = math.floor(length2) 
        ceiling = math.ceil(length2)
        total = sorted2[floored] + sorted2[ceiling]
        finalmedian = total/2
        print("MEDIAN: " + str(finalmedian))
    
    
else:
        median = str(sorted2[length1/2])
        print("MEDIAN:"+ str(median))
```

Comment: You are aware that numpy has a median function? And scipy has a mode function.

Comment: In a sorted list the median is the value under len(list)/2 if uneven amount of numbers, and the halved sum of the values under len(list)/2-1 and len(list)/2  - not sure what you are doing with numpy here

Comment: Use integer division: `length1//2` instead of `length1/2`, so you don't accidentally end up with floating point numbers as indices.

Comment: You can directly use numpy.median instead of writing this long program.